# Layout actionbar appcompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I am using an `appcompat` v7 actionbar with `sliding tabs and navigational drawer`. Reference taken from [here](https://github.com/AtomicSpider/Tinder-Like-Action-Bar). As you can see in the image, the tabs are not evenly spaced in the `tabViewBar`. I want to modify the layout of the actionbar, such that it spans out evenly to use the space.

This is how the `tabBarView` initializes and add the `tabViews`:

```
public class TabBarView extends LinearLayout {
public TabBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        setWillNotDraw(false);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mStripHeight = (int) (STRIP_HEIGHT * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + .5f);
    }

private void addTabViewP(final int i, final String string, int pageIconResId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (i == 0) {
            tabView1 = new TabView(getContext());
            tabView1.setIcon(pageIconResId);
            tabView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            });
            CheatSheet.setup(tabView1, string);
            this.addView(tabView1);
        } else if (i == 1) {
            tabView2 = new TabView(getContext());
            tabView2.setIcon(pageIconResId);
            tabView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            });
            CheatSheet.setup(tabView2, string);
            this.addView(tabView2);
        } else if (i == 2) {
            tabView3 = new TabView(getContext());
            tabView3.setIcon(pageIconResId);
            tabView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            });
            CheatSheet.setup(tabView3, string);
            this.addView(tabView3);
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the `tabBarView` custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sanat.tinderactionbar.tabbarview.TabBarView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customTabBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</com.sanat.tinderactionbar.tabbarview.TabBarView>
```

Here is the `styles.xml` file:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_grey_700</item>
</style>
```

I tried to add `<item name="weightSum">4<item>` in my parent theme, but no change takes place.

Even when I modify the `setLayoutParams` in `TabBarView` to:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.weight = 0;
setLayoutParams(params);
```

This doesnt work either. Where and how should I change the layout/code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

So: horizontal linear layout, full screen on width, right?

Don't set `weightSum` on the parent. For the (4?) children views: set `width=0` and `weight=1`. This gives them equal importance without having to divide by their number (they are still going to be equally divided if you add a fifth one). In xml you'd have something like this (please excuse my random image choice from Android's resources and my choice of control (ImageView) - you might have to play with the gravity and layout_gravity if you include some other layouts):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am not using xml layout for setting up `tabBarView`.. can you tell me how to do this using `layoutparams` programmatically?

Comment: Here's an example using `LinearLayout` and `Button`s placed inside it: LinearLayout.LayoutParams lP1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 lP1.weight = 1;
 Button bt1 = new Button(ll.getContext());
 bt1.setLayoutParams(lP1);
 bt1.setText("Button1");
 linearLayout.addView(bt1);

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lP2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 ...

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lP3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 ...